# Rails Compile error for form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am getting the an error on the following code in one of my partial views

```
<% form_for (@user) |form| %>
```

SyntaxError in User#edit

Showing user/_user_edit_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

compile error
../app/views/user/_user_edit_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ';'
_erbout = '';  form_for (@user) |form| ; _erbout.concat "\n"

Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the do:

```
<% form_for (@user) do |form| %>
```